# Array Formula that drops two lowest values and then averages a total

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I am in need of some help creating an array formula to help organize student grades. After six tests I would like to drop the two lowest scores for each student and then average the remaining four. The array formula would start in H2 in the attached link. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z-4hzwBK6YUuFncZsN2NhNF8eDnCEKJ9XLmKHnoJQQE/edit?usp=sharing

The closest I can get is summing the four largest amounts and then averaging them out but I have to do this for every line.  I am hoping to make an array formula so I can easily copy this to different class sizes per semester.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=byrow(B2:G,lambda(Σ,if(offset(index(Σ,,1),,-1)="",,round(average(sortn(tocol(Σ),4,,1,0)),2))))
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your help.  Can you explain the beginning part of the formula with lambda and offset?

Comment: [lambda](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) is alike custom function with a given symbol identifier Σ here in this case. byrow uses this to iterate one row at a time to output top 4 values found. offset here is being used to point at Column_A and saying to execute the logic as long as its not found empty. alternatively the offset part can also be replaced with `if(counta(Σ)=0,,`

Comment: using your alternative **LARGE** Fx: `=byrow(B2:index(G:G,match(2,1/(A:A<>""))),lambda(top_four,average(index(LARGE(top_four,{1,2,3,4})))))`

Comment: You've been a HUGE help so far. Can you break this part of the equation down for me... B2:index(G:G,match(2,1/(A:A<>""))).   From best I can tell thats the part of the formula that finds the last row of data?

Comment: It's creating a range from `B2` to the last used row of column `G`. You should click `accept` on the answer given that it addressed your question.

Answer (score 1):

This one isn't much different than RockShow, but it has a dynamic element to it for one variable of number of tests to drop so it might be a little more flexible along with the range. In case it's not obvious, changing the `2` after `testsToDrop` will adjust the output accordingly.

```
=let(testsToDrop,2,byrow(filter(B2:G,A2:A<>""),lambda(aRow,(sum(arow)
  -sum(ARRAYFORMULA(small(aRow,SEQUENCE(1,testsToDrop,1,1)))))/
    (count(arow)-testsToDrop))))
```